# How to ship powershell module to production environment?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-module

I have written all my powershell functions in a ps1 file.

In another ps1 file ,it is being dot sourced and function are being called.

When i look for better methods i came to know that putting all the functions as modules (.psm1) is better option.

But for .ps1 file i can simply it in a folder and ship it.

With .psm1 file ,it says i have to add it to particular location so that it can be imported.

how to provide .psm1 file to customer then ? should we instruct them to copy to the mentioned location before using it ? (if we don't ship via msi)

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can import psm1 files via path but that isn't the best user experience.  If you put the file in a folder under either $home\documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules or $pshome\Modules then the user can import based on just the name of the psm1 file.  Finally, you can put the psm1 file in any location you want and if you modify the PSModulePath environment variable to include that directory, PowerShell will search for modules in that dir.

Comment: As for the specific section part of his question, that's not really required as far as I know.  Instead of dot sourcing it you run Import-Module modulepath.psm1. However you can add the Export-ModuleMember cmdlet to the PSM1 file.  If this is done you will have to export every member you'd like to be able to be imported.  If you omit export-modulemember it will export every module in the PSM1 by default.

Comment: If you omit `Export-ModuleMember` it will export every function but none of the variables.